# Can I still use a service instance after ungetting it?

Tags: osgi

Is this a valid operation to do?

```
final IOSGiService service = (IOSGiService) bundleContext.getService(reference);
bundleContext.ungetService(reference);
service.executeSomeOperaton();
```

Will I be able to run the method `executeSomeOperaton()` safely every time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have the object and you will be able to call functions on it. However, you cannot be sure that the object is still in the right state. What if the provider of the Service closes some resource that is necessary for that function work well?

You should not use services in this way. You cannot even be sure that the service is in the right state when you call the function on it even if you have not called *unget()*. You should use a technology like [Felix Felix SCR](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-service-component-runtime.html). In that case your object will be deactivated if the reference is not available anymore, or if you specified reference to be dynamic, an unbind method will be called on your object. From that, you will know when the service is truly available.

Alternatives to use: [Apache Felix iPojo](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-ipojo.html), [Apache Aries Blueprint](http://aries.apache.org/modules/blueprint.html) or use a [ServiceTracker](http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v42/org/osgi/util/tracker/ServiceTracker.html) to catch the events of the service that you use.

**Update**:

*So in other words ungetting a service or not will do no difference at all, unless I really want to keep the service usage counter correct right?*

There are cases where ungetting the service really matters. For example, if the Provider registered a [ServiceFactory](http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v43/core/org/osgi/framework/ServiceFactory.html) instead of the service object itself, it is possible to catch the unget event on the Provider side. In that case, resources might be freed as soon as the unget is called on the service.

As much as I remember all service references of the consumer bundle are retrieved (unget is called) when the consumer bundle is stopped (but I am not sure).

Comment: I agree with what Balazs says and would like to add that you can never be sure your service is still available when you invoke a method on it. You should always expect a runtime exception (like you would when invoking a remote method). Using frameworks might hide this fact (which might or might not be a good thing) but it is something you should deal with.

Comment: Thanks! I must look into this SCR deeply. It doesn't look like an easy concept to grasp.
So in other words ungetting a service or not will do no difference at all, unless I really want to keep the service usage counter correct right? Shouldn't the OSGi Framework handle this counter by itself instead of pushing the incrementation and decrementation responsability to us?